# Getting error when click Submit in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, form-submit

Controller File Code : EmergencyContactsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\EmergencyContacts;

class EmergencyContactsController extends Controller
  {
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
 }

 public function create(){
     return view('patient/emergencycontacts');      
 }
 public function store(array $data){

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); die();
 }
}
```

Routes File Code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
 });

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@index' ) ;

Route::get('/emergencycontacts_create' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@create' ) ;

//Route::post('/emergncycontacts_store' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@store' ) ;


Route::post('/emergencycontacts_store', ['uses' => 'patient/EmergencyContacts@store', 'as' => 'emergencycontacts_store']);

Route::resource('/patient/emergency-contacts', 'EmergencyContactsController');
```

Blade file Code : patient/emergencycontacts.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'emergencycontacts_store', 'class' => 'form')) !!}
 <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('Salutation') !!}
  {{ Form::select('salutation', ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss.','Ms.']) }}
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('First Name') !!}
{!! Form::text('firstname', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'First Name')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Last Name') !!}
{!! Form::text('lastname', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Last Name')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Relationship') !!}
{{ Form::select('relationship', ['Father', 'Mother', 'Husband','Wife','Son','Daughter','Uncle','Aunty','Other']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Phone') !!}
{!! Form::text('phone', null, array('required'ReflectionException in Container.php line 719: Class App\Http\Controllers\patient/EmergencyContacts does not exist, 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Phone')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Fax') !!}
{!! Form::text('fax', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Fax')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::submit('Save',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When I try to submit it give me the following error. I am new in laravel.
Getting error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 719: Class App\Http\Controllers\patient/EmergencyContacts does not exist
```

Comment: you are passing namespace inside route instead of controller name

Comment: Is that fine Now? Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index'); Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@index' ) ; Route::get('/patient/emergencycontacts_create' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@create' ) ; Route::post('/patient/emergencycontacts_store', ['uses' => 'EmergencyContactsController@store', 'as' => 'emergencycontacts_store']); Route::resource('/patient/emergency-contacts', 'EmergencyContactsController');

Comment: Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts' , 'EmergencyContactsController@index' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the controller's path given in the routes/web.php file:

```
 'EmergencyContactsController@...'
```

Store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($request->all()); 
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

Comment: My controller file is not inside patient folder. Controller file just inside the controller folder but my blade file is exist in patient folder.

Comment: updated the answer now, you gave the wrong path to the controller in the routes file then

Comment: I have updated this line in route "Route::post('/emergencycontacts_store', ['uses' => 'EmergencyContactsController@store', 'as' => 'emergencycontacts_store']);". and now I am getting this error "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\EmergencyContactsController::store()".

Comment: Is that fine Now?
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@index' ) ;
Route::get('/patient/emergencycontacts_create' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@create' ) ;
Route::post('/patient/emergencycontacts_store', ['uses' => 'EmergencyContactsController@store', 'as' => 'emergencycontacts_store']);
Route::resource('/patient/emergency-contacts', 'EmergencyContactsController');